# How to send WebSocket events from blocking operation? (Design advice needed)

Tags: html, perl, websocket, mojolicious

I use Mojolicious WebSocket to establish server-client messaging protocol.

There is long-time operation on server and I want update its progress on client-side.

In several points on server-side code I call `$web_socket->send(...)` and process it on client-side `ws.onmessage = function (event) {...};`

Everything work fine, but not in realtime: all messages has received by client at one big bulk list and only after whole server-side script has finished.

Server-side logic:

```
some_computation1();
$web_socket->send('computation1 end');
...
some_computation15();
$web_socket->send('computation15 end');
...
some_computation100();
$web_socket->send('computation100 end. All ok!');
```

Client-side:

```
ws = new WebSocket(url);
ws.onmessage = function (event) {
    $('#log_view').append('<p>' + event.data + '</p>');
};
ws.onopen = function (event) {
    ... 
};
ws.onclose = function (event) {
    ...
};
```

Comment: Is your "long running operation" blocking the server's ioloop? That would certainly cause the observed behavior. I can't comment further without seeing more code.

Comment: @Joel Berger, there is about 3k lines code of server logic and its very similar to short example above. Yes, that operation is blocking ioloop. I didn't find the way to "process events" (like in Qt). I tried use Mojo::IOLoop timer and threads to sending websocket messages, but no luck.

Comment: Consider moving the long computation to a separate thread or (even better) break it down to a number of tasks and callbacks, allowing for the native reactor / event handler to manage concurrency and send/receive IO data.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found this works for me: **Mojo::IOLoop->one_tick;**

```
some_computation1();
$web_socket->send('computation1 end');
Mojo::IOLoop->one_tick;
```

UPD: or may be it will be better to separate long operation in background thread ('fork' or 'delay').

Comment: This will work until your your hypnotoad workers start to die off due to lack of heartbeat

Comment: @JoelBerger, thanks for your warning, but it doesn't solve this problem :) What about other web servers with websockets support? Same bad thing? Where I can find more information about how all of this works under-hood? (IOLoop + WebSocket + Webserver (hypnotoad, daemon, mod_perl...)

Answer (score 3):

[There is](https://gist.github.com/Logioniz/a46b4b6420254398712b) two example how to make it using one of two modules:

1. [Mojo::IOLoop::ReadWriteFork](https://metacpan.org/pod/Mojo::IOLoop::ReadWriteFork)
2. [Mojo::IOLoop::ForkCall](https://metacpan.org/pod/Mojo::IOLoop::ForkCall)

To run it execute command:
`perl perl_ws_long_blocking_operation.pl daemon`

**Upd.**
If you have many long blocking operations you should use `Mojo::IOLoop::Delay`:

[Example of many long blocking operation](https://gist.github.com/Logioniz/f94921ddc33d6a9b6605)

To run it execute command:

```
morbo perl_ws_many_long_blocking_operations.pl
```

Comment: Thanks for solution. I tried ForkCall. I want to send websocket message in "background" and big logic — in main thread, not vice versa. I tried send websocket message in ForkCall (ws setup still in main thread), but it don't sending at all.

Comment: I can't understand why this not working for you. I update answer to combine Mojo::IOLoop::Delay with Mojo::IOLoop::ForkCall.

Comment: ок, I'll try it. I accept your answer If this solution will be better than mine.